# Does Yii::$app>request->post() clean $_POST variables?

Tags: php, post, yii2

Just want to know if Yii2 cleans the `$_POST` variables if I use this method:

```
Yii::$app->request->post()
```

If suppose I am using the following method to get the value of `x`:

```
$x = Yii::$app->request->post('x');
```

Does Yii2 framework internally cleans the `$_POST` variable? Or else we have to do it manually?

Answer (score 3):

No, the `$_POST` stays untouched, in its initial condition.

Yii just copies and holds it in private `$_bodyParams` property.

And I don't think it's a good practice to manually modify or clean `$_POST` parameters.

Comment: So when we load the model using Yii::$app->request->post() and then save it. Isn't it insecure?

Comment: It's completely different question. But in brief - it's secure if you set validation rules properly.

Comment: And also purify HTML content if it's needed.